# transform month to discrete time periods

Tags: python, datetime

Let us say I have a list of dates in datetime.date format.  I want to transform date in months into discrete (integer) periods.

I.e.,

```
myList = [datetime.date(2015,02,08), datetime.date(2015,02,25), datetime.date(2015,05,03), datetime.date(2016,03,27)]
```

Since the smallest year/month is 2015/02 then that month is equivalent to 0.  The next month 2015/03 would be 1, etc.  Until last month 2016/03 would be 13.

I'd want a function for which I give it the start date, and then it gives me the discrete month.

I.e.,

```
discretizeMo(start_date, date_of_interest)
discretizeMo('2012-02-01', '2013-01-01')
```

would return 11, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you drop the days, the usual date arithmetic is of no use here. The simplest solution would be to convert years & months to a scale:

```
def discretizeMo(d1, d2):
    return (d2.year * 12 + d2.month) - (d1.year * 12 + d1.month)
```

The result is the number of months passed since the `d1` date till the `d2` date.

That simple.

If you want to split it into smaller units of fixed length (e.g., weeks), it will be different:

```
def discretizeMo(d1, d2):
    return (d2 - d1).days // 7
```

The difference comes from the variable duration of months in days: 28-29-30-31.

Comment: what if I want to discretize time into weeks? then a year has 52 weeks... but I assume it gets a bit more complicated...

Comment: @Dnaiel Added the answer for the weeks. The math will be different in that case. Because months have varying number of days, so the "year-month math" & "day math" are different.

Comment: This works, but it relies in a pretty subtle way on the fact that timedeltas in Python get normalized into a unique representation of days, seconds, microseconds.

Comment: @wim Well, yes. This is Python, where things are simple. In other languages without such normalization, it will be a mess of 30/31-day months, Februaries, non-leap regular years, leap years by mod 4, non-leap years by mod 100, leap year by mod 400… In any case, putting every date to a scale of days since time 0, and then subtracting, and then calculating that mess back into months. Luckily, no time involved, which would make it even worse.

Answer (score 2):

You could subtract the year parts, multiply it by 12 to get the difference in months and then subtract the month parts:

```
def discretizeMo(start_date, end_date):
    return (end_date.year - start_date.year) * 12 + \
           (end_date.month - start_date.month)
```

From there on, it's just a matter of applying this function between each element and the minimum:

```
result = [discretizeMo(min(myList), x) for x in myList]
```

Comment: what if I wanted to discretize it in weeks for example? I'm trying to use a general formula...

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty easy, since there will always be 12 months in a year:

```
def discretizeMo(d0, d):
    return (d.year - d0.year)*12 + d.month - d0.month
```

If you're dealing with multiple timezones, you might want to make sure that `d0` and `d` have the same timezone, otherwise you could get incorrect results.

Comment: I am trying to come up with a general formula, what if I wanted to discretize them in weeks?

Comment: The result depends on which day you consider the start of the week.  So you have to make a decision about that, first.

Comment: good point.  that's right let us say the day is the day of the start date that we use as d0.  I.e., for our example it'd be datetime.date(2015,02,08) and that'd be day 0, week 0.